# Is there a way to change the titleView of the navigation item without using code

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

Say I just want to do it through storyboard instead of coding. I want to turn the titleView into a searchbar.

Comment: Isn't its `titleView` property an outlet? Is in my IB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know what got me but yes you can easily add searchBar to navigationController Title View.

Just drag that searchBar to the location.

It seems that I must have missed that somehow. It works fine. I think somehow it didn't work before but it works fine now. I am not sure what happened.

Here is screenshot

[image]

Note: You can only add textView. Not UIView or UIImageView it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You just double click on the navigation bar, then you will be allowed to enter text. The text you enter is the title of the navigation bar

It's available only on storyBoard.

Comment: That won't help with the title view though.

Comment: the question was about title VIEW but not title itself

Comment: Well, I want to change the titleView into something more elaborate like a searchbar.